# Project, rescale and clip rasters

Tags: raster, r

I have a list of rasters in a folder that I want to project, rescale values and clip. My current code looks like this

```
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(raster

setwd("D:/working")

# define projections
utm33s <- CRS('+proj=utm +zone=33 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0')

# read in and stack files
r.list <- list.files(pattern="*.tif", full.names=TRUE)
r.stack <- stack(r.list)

# project stack to utm 33s
r.stack.prj = projectRaster(r.stack, crs = utm33s)

# function to calculate float values
fun <- fun <- function(x) {
  y = (x - 50) / 200
  return(y)
}

# apply function on the stack
calc(r.stack.prj, fun=fun)

# read in polygon file for use in clipping
aoi = readOGR(dsn=".", layer="aoi_shape")

# clip raster using polygon
r.stack.prj <- crop(r.stack.prj, aoi, snap="out") 

# save as GeoTIFF
writeRaster(r.stack.prj, 'clean_stack.tif', overwrite=TRUE)
```

The script crashes at 'projectRaster' What I'm I doing doing wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? It appears that the initial rasters might not have a coordinate system assigned to start with in the first place.

Comment: @Vijay-ramesh The rasters have this coordinate system `+proj=sinu +lon_0=20 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs` assigned.

Comment: As already commented, difficult to help unless you report also which specific error you are getting.

Comment: can you provide details of one file, i.e. the printed output of  'raster(r.list[1])' - my feeling is this sinu projection is probably of far greater extent than the valid range for this UTM zone. Generally reprojection of rasters is ill-advised, usually it's better to calculate in the native projection of the gridded data, and transform other vector data to that space for extractions etc. Also UTM is a very poor choice, in the general case - it's probably unnecessary and possibly a bad choice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest doing this instead:

```
r.stack <- stack(r.list)
calc.stack <- calc(r.stack.prj, fun=fun)
aoi = readOGR(dsn=".", layer="aoi_shape")
r.stack.crop <- crop(calc.stack, spTransform(aoi, projection(calc.stack), snap="out")
```

Then if really necessary, projectRaster the r.stack.crop - don't do it before the other operations, it's merely wasteful and destructive (in the technical senses).